# How to debug "Gas estimation failed: 'The execution failed due to an exception.'" in brownie?

Tags: python, blockchain, solidity, brownie

Is there any general way to trace where this error occurs? It seems like a  pretty common error, but I don't know any way to debug it.

Do I have to always manually and thoroughly review my function and transaction calls both in python and solidity?

Especially when project is more complex and uses external contracts this process can be very tedious and time-consuming.

Thanks for any response

Answer (score 0):

That messages means that the function reverted somewhere. If you go on etherscan or any other block explorer you can check the emitted events during the transaction so you can see where the flow stops.

Comment: But how to obtain transaction hash? Normally brownie returns it from the transaction call, but in this case brownie doesn't assign anything, just throws this error. Trying wrapping it in try-except doesn't help, and hash isn't displayed in console either, just error.

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to this. Basically when you get that error, it means that the transaction is not even sent to the blockchain, because it fails some preliminary check. You  could force the transaction adding the parameters 'gas_limit' and 'allow_revert', so that you get the tx receipt and can debug that. I wonder if there is way to debug without sending the tx (and spending fees) though.